# Return defaul value of hash ruby

Tags: ruby

I am making a hash like this:

```
enum_gender={:male=>1,:female=>2, :default_when_fail=>3}
```

but I need that when I access

```
enum_gender[:somekey]
```

It return 3 by default or some value specified

```
:some_key could be any other :assd, :asf, :asdf
```

how do I do this ?

Comment: Have you checked the hash docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `fetch`:

```
enum_gender={:male=>1,:female=>2}
enum_gender.fetch(key, 3)

enum_gender.fetch('a_non_key', 3) #=> 3
```

Comment: Can you select it as an "answer" if it helped? @DarlyncinhoBravo

Answer (score 2):

You can do this

```
enum_gender = Hash.new(3).merge({:male=>1,:female=>2})
=> {:male=>1, :female=>2}

enum_gender[:somekey]
=> 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest writing some kind of conditional.  You could write it as its own function, an if/else/end block, or a ternary as you like.

Example:

```
if enum_gender.has_key?(key)
  return enum_gender[key]
else
  return <default value>
end
```